# How to swap ETH to ERC20 tokens with smart contract

Tags: tokens, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets

How can I swap ETH to ERC20 tokens?

For example, I have 10 ETH and I want to swap 8 ETH to USDT.

I do not want to use any exchange, swap website such as uniswap, etc.

I want to change myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you've enough liquidity, you can use an oracle like chainlink and swap inside your smart contract/website with some simple logic.

But in most cases, we don't have enough liquidity. So the uniswap contract comes in handy.

You can import the UniSwap router inside your smart contract and do the swap within your same smart contract in one atomic transaction.

This should be helpful: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/quick-start

The swap will happen as an atomic transaction, so you can perform as many swaps in one transaction from your smart contract.